# Replace every vowel with random vowels and every consonant with random consonants in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, random, replace

I need a function that takes a string and replaces every vowel in it with random vowels and every consonant in it with random consonants and returns the new string with the same capitalization as the original in Javascript. Is there a fast way to do it?

For example:
If the string is “John” then it could return “Lavr” or “Xiqp”.

Comment: Have you tried building it? It is certainly possible and the fast part depends totally on how you build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible. 
Firstly, create an array of vowels and consonants. 
Create a loop to loop through your original string, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  const currentChar = str.charAt(i)
}
```

Within this loop, check if you char is upper or lower case using string prototype methods:

```
currentChar.toLowerCase() === currentChar
```

See if your char is a vowel or consonant:

```
vowels.find(currentChar)
```

This will result in -1 if element is not found, you can use this value to determine the type of character.

Then, use JS Math to choose a random character from your vowel or consonant array.

```
vowels[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowels.length)]
```

Use the above value to replace that character. Repeat for each char and put it all back together with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a full list of consonants and vowels to compare against, so make variables for both of those. Then, loop through the string, checking if each letter is a lowercase vowel, lowercase consonant, uppercase vowel, uppercase consonant, or something else. If you find something lowercase, just replace it with a random character from your corresponding vowels/consonants variable using [Randojs](https://randojs.com)'s `rando()` function. If you find that something is uppercase, replace it with a random uppercase character from the corresponding variable using JavaScript's built-in [`toUppercase()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) method. Otherwise, if it's not a letter, just add it to the string as-is.

```js
function chaos(str) {
  var consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
  var vowels = "aeiou";

  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) newStr += rando(vowels);
    else if (consonants.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) newStr += rando(consonants);
    else if (vowels.toUpperCase().indexOf(str[i]) > -1) newStr += rando(vowels.toUpperCase());
    else if (consonants.toUpperCase().indexOf(str[i]) > -1) newStr += rando(consonants.toUpperCase());
    else newStr += str[i];
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(chaos("This is CHAOS."));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Note that the `rando()` function is from [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), so you just have to make sure this is at the top in the head tag of your html document if you want to use this code:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

It just makes the randomness simpler and more readable.

**Side note:** For next time, please remember to post the code you've already tried instead of just asking a question. This site is here to help when you hit a wall, but you can't hit a wall if you haven't written anything.